# SSH from iPhone to iPhone - Trying to transfer sms.db file

Tags: sms, terminal

I'm trying to put together the terminal command so I can ssh to a friends iPhone and copy his sms.db file to my device. I'm using mobile terminal.

This is what I've put together so far.

scp root@IPHONE_IP_ADDRESS:directory_of_file directory_where_file_is_copied_on_my_device

```
scp root@192.168.1.102:/private/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db /var
```

I'm then asked for password, I enter it and I get this.

```
 /var/sms.db: Permission Denied
```

Can someone tell me whats needed or what my mistake is? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you need to setup the permissions properly (`chmod`) OR use a different folder with the appropriate permissions/rights.

Comment: It's been a loong night. I just needed to login. su Doh! Script works perfectly now. SMS Thief Script. Haha.